# Generating Time slots between two time for today

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am editing my question little bit

I have Office Timing Table As follows.

```
TIME_FROM   TIME_TO     TIME_FROM1    TIME_TO1 TIME_FROM2               TIME_TO2
07:00 AM    14:00 PM    700           1400     06/08/2020 07:00:00 AM   06/08/2020 02:00:00 PM
16:00 PM    18:00 PM    1600          1800     06/08/2020 04:00:00 PM   06/08/2020 06:00:00 PM
```

Office Starting time is 7.00 AM and ending time is 6.00 PM with break time in between.This Times can vary based on selected Office.

Input parameters are

1.Travel Time in minutes to reach Office

2.Time slot duration in minutes

After taking Travel Time in minutes into consideration,I want to generate time slots of 15 minute(variable) interval between these time ranges like

7.00 AM

7.15 AM

7.30 AM

7.45 AM

8.00 AM
.

.

.

.

1.30 PM

1.45 PM

2.00 PM

Second Shift starts here

4.00 PM

4.15 PM

4.30 PM

.

.

.

.

.

5.30 PM

5.45 PM

**Scenario 1 :**

Travel time needed :31 minutes

Booking attempt time 6.15 AM

Office Opening Time 7.00 AM

Required result

7.00

7.15

.

.
1.45 PM( Dont include shift ending time 2.00PM)

4.00 PM

4.15 PM

.

.
5.45 PM

**Scenario 2 :**

Travel time needed :31 minutes

Booking attempt time 6.45 AM

Office Opening Time 7.00 AM

Required result

7.16

7.31

.

.
1.46 PM( Dont include shift ending time 2.00PM)

4.00 PM

4.15 PM

.

.
5.45 PM

**Scenario 3 :**

Travel time needed :31 minutes

Booking attempt time 9.45 AM

Office Opening Time 7.00 AM

Required result

10.16

10.31

.

.
1.46 PM( Dont include shift ending time 2.00PM)

4.00 PM

4.15 PM

.

.
5.45 PM

**Scenario 4 :**

Travel time needed :31 minutes

Booking attempt time 3 PM

Office Second shift opening Time 4.00 PM

Required result

04.00 PM

04.15 PM

.

.
5.45 PM( Dont include shift ending time 18.00PM)

**Scenario 5 :**

Travel time needed :31 minutes

Booking attempt time 3.45 PM

Office Second shift opening Time 4.00 PM

Required result

04.16 PM

04.31 PM

.

.
5.46 PM( Dont include shift ending time 18.00PM)

Comment: In the above table TIME_FROM and TIME_TO are office start and end time.Could also show sample output or you just need one column ?

Comment: I just need one column Time Slots preferably with todays date.

Comment: That 2nd paragraph, starting with "One condition" - how does that map to your sample data ? What is "current time" does that map to any column ? You are showing a table but also mentioning current time -does that mean that you have to generate the slots at a point in time ? eg when current time is 10:02 AM, how is that related to the 7:00 AM office starting time ?

Comment: If the Query ran before 7.00 AM the your solution is correct.Starting Time is 7.00AM. But if i run the query after 7 AM then starting time should be considered as current time.Suppose its 10.02 AM and add 15 minutes to it.So result should be  10.02AM,10.17AM,10.32 AM like that..

Comment: updated answer. Pls comment on answer and not on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH 
--cte to determine office hours, this is probably a table irl
office_timing (id, time_from2, time_to2) AS
(
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE('09/08/2020 07:00:00 AM','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),     TO_DATE('09/08/2020 02:00:00 PM','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TO_DATE('09/08/2020 04:00:00 PM','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),     TO_DATE('09/08/2020 06:00:00 PM','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') FROM dual
)
--cte to determine when travel time to office, replace with other values to test. Make this a variable if it is an input parameter
,travel_time (travel_mins) AS
(
  SELECT 31 FROM DUAL
)
--cte to determine slot length, replace with other values to test. Make this a variable if it is an input parameter
,
slot_minutes (mins) AS
(
  SELECT 15 FROM DUAL
)
--cte to determine when query is run, replace with other values to test. Make this a variable if it is an input parameter
,run_date_tab (run_date) AS
(
SELECT 
    TO_DATE('09/08/2020 03:45:00 PM','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') + travel_mins/1440    
  FROM travel_time
)

--cte to determine start time based on the query run date
--  if run date is in a time slot then take run date
--  if run date is outside time slot then take closest future start date
,
start_time_tab (qry_start_time) AS
(
  SELECT MIN(CASE 
           WHEN  t.time_from2 <= r.run_date AND t.time_to2 > r.run_date
             THEN r.run_date
           WHEN  t.time_from2 > r.run_date 
             THEN t.time_from2
         ELSE 
           NULL
         END)
    FROM run_date_tab r  
         CROSS JOIN office_timing t
        
)
,slots (slot_start_time) AS
(
  SELECT 
    s.qry_start_time +(level - 1) / ((60/m.mins)*24)
    FROM start_time_tab s CROSS JOIN slot_minutes m CONNECT BY
    level < 100
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(s.slot_start_time,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')  
  FROM slots s
       JOIN office_timing t ON t.time_from2 < s.slot_start_time AND t.time_to2 > s.slot_start_time;
```

Comment: 10 minute interval is not fixed.Its a variable.How to fix that? Also you passed 7/24 manually. 7 is not fixed time.It depends on starting time which can vary

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please look my edited question

Comment: What did you try so far based on the answerd you got ? where did you get stuck ?

Comment: @Koren Lostrie. Its including Shift end time slot also. Like 2.00PM AND 6.00 PM. It should be excluded from the result. Also 7.00 AM is not fixed branch timing.I tcan be 7.30 or 7.15 or 8 or any other timing.So it should be a parameter to pass

Comment: This should do, you can replace make slot time, travel time, run time variables to suit your needs. I documented the cte's. Study the code so you understand what it does and change it to your needs

Comment: It is returning only second shift slots even when the sys date time is 7.00 or 8.00 .Am i missing anything here?

Comment: you mean when you run the query as it is posted ? Yes that is correct. Please read the comments for each cte. The example posted is for 09/08/2020 03:45:00 PM. As the comments state - replace with what you need: sysdate,  another test date etc. Please take the time to examine the code before asking more questions.

Comment: Oops..Sorry Mr.Koen Lostrie..My mistake..Thank you so much.Seems like i got what i needed..

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a fairly comprehensive date (including timestamp) handling functions. Generally I live by the axiom that once a column is converted to date the only reason to convert to a string it to create a display column. There are however exceptions. One of those is (often times) when the date needs to be sliced and diced and reassembled. That is the case here to properly calculate the end time by your 'match the minute run' requirement .

You are not going to get shift break line from an SQL solution, at least I'm going to do it. You could with PL/SQL by iterating over the results. However, that is an easy task for your presentation layer. I have added a column to the final result indicating the shift. With that in mind:

```
with time_range (sts, ets)  as 
     ( select case when extract(hour from systimestamp) <= 07
                   then trunc(systimestamp) + interval '07:00' hour to minute 
                   else trunc(systimestamp, 'mi') 
               end sot            
            , case when extract(hour from systimestamp) <= 07
                   then trunc(systimestamp) + interval '18:00' hour to minute  
                   else to_timestamp(to_char(systimestamp,'yyyymmdd') || '18' || to_char(systimestamp,'mi'), 'yyyymmddhh24mi')  
               end eot             
         from dual
     ) 
    , office_hours (start_time, end_time) as
      ( select * from time_range
        union all
        select start_time+interval '15' minute, end_time
          from office_hours
         where start_time < end_time 
      ) 
select to_char(start_time, 'hh.mi am')
     , case when 60 * extract(hour   from cast( start_time as timestamp))
                    + extract(minute from cast( start_time as timestamp)) <= 14*60 
            then 'first shift'
            else 'second shift'
       end shift
  from office_hours;
```

What it does:  
The work of the query is done in 2 CTEs and a select using them:

1. time_range: determines the start and end times necessary given the
   current time (on the server).
2. office_hours: a recursive CTE that computes the 15 minute intervals
   for start to end times.
3. Main: Select the start of the range and determines shift.

See fiddle for [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=81a8c6a4a09b3d8e80c1ddb80dfd1441). Note: In its current form the query will always return at least 1 row. If run after the end time, it returns a row indication that time.  
 There are 2 additional queries with a slight modification allowing actual specification of run time instead of getting that from the system. for these I have "set the runtime" in them to  07:00 and 09:02 respectively.

Comment: Too complex for me.Also starting time and ending time can vary.You put it manually everywhere..I want to use starting time and ending time from table

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please look my edited question for more clarity.